# paypal payment integration from asp.net page

Tags: vb.net, paypal

can anyone detail the particulars that are required to send data collected from a asp.net web page using vb.net that has a bunch of text boxes for first name, last name, address... item price, quantity, total price... to paypal for processing and settlement?

i have never worked with paypal so i am assuming paypal will get this info and generate a bill to send the user.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The following [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET) should explain much of the process to you. For further reading you can also check out the PayPal developer [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/accept-payments/).

**Update**:

Here is an updated [example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal) for current version of ASP.NET (4.5 at the time of writing)

Comment: Your article link looks broken.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate PayPal into website vb.net

1. Open cmd enter "http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245" (install windows update for nuGetPackage)
2. Open cmd enter `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v   DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:32`(Register cmd update)
3. Register nuGet update in solution of the project.
   Goto : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/
4. NuGet clients and PowerShell reg.
5. Install Paypal nuGet package in solution
6. Add Paypal SDK reference in the project.
7. Add configurations for Paypal.
8. NuGet manager package JSON uninstall.
9. Tools -> nuget manager-> package manager console paste `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.1`, enter.
10. Add in vb file of startupwizard the code in paypal1.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXChrl0XWR_sE_rZCtGAvgWu24C55KEV/view?usp=sharing